# Expectation and variance of occurrences of patterns in a random text

Tags: statistics, biology

I'm not sure how to complete the following problem from the book *An Introduction to Bioinformatics Algorithms*:

> **Problem 9.1**
>
> Derive the expectation and the variance of the number of occurrences of patterns AA and AT in a random text of length n. Are the expectations and variances for AA and AT the same?

For AA, I think the expectation would be $\frac{n-1}{16}$ ($n-1$ possible 2-base positions times the probability of AA, $\frac{1}{16}$). But for AT, I'm not sure because this sequence cannot overlap (*i.e.* it can occurs at most $\frac{n}{2}$ times).

Also, I don't know how to calculate the variance.

Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For every $xy$ and every $k$, let $U_k(xy)$ denote the indicator of the event that the portion $\{k,k+1\}$ of the sequence is $xy$. One is interested in
$$
N=\sum_{k=1}^{n-1}U_k(AA),\qquad M=\sum_{k=1}^{n-1}U_k(AT).
$$
Obviously, $E[U_k(xy)]=\frac1{16}$ for every $k$ and $xy$, hence $E[N]=E[M]=\frac1{16}(n-1)$.

To compute the variances, start with $N^2$, say, which is
$$
N^2=\sum_{k=1}^{n-1}U_k(AA)+2\sum_{k=1}^{n-2}U_k(AA)U_{k+1}(AA)+2\sum_{k=1}^{n-3}\sum_{\ell=k+2}^{n-1}U_k(AA)U_\ell(AA).
$$
Surely you can compute the expectation of each term, sum them, and substract the square of the expectation. This will yield $\mathrm{var}(N)$ (*which might be something like $\frac1{16}(5n-7)$*).

Likewise for $M$, with the same technique but a different end result because $U_k(AT)U_{k+1}(AT)$ behaves differently than $U_k(AA)U_{k+1}(AA)$. This will yield $\mathrm{var}(M)$  (*which might be something like $\frac3{16}(n-1)$*).

Comment: @Peter Indeed users posting a question and never reacting to the answers they get, are a plague for the site. I used to post comments asking for such a reaction, if only to know that my answer had been read, but got tired of doing it.